# Pegar valor de todos os checkbox marcados

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Como faço para pegar todos os valores de checkbox que forem marcados e passar pra o GET.

```js
$("#subcategoria").click(function(){

            var checados = [];
            $.each($("input[name='subcategoria[]']:checked"), function(){

                $.get("inc_habilidades.php",
                    {id:checados.push($(this).val()),  opcao:'2'},
                    function(valor2){
                        $("#habilidades").html(valor2).chosen("destroy");
                    }
                )
            });

        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="">
    <input class="subcategoria" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" value="1" />teste1<br>
    <input class="subcategoria" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" value="2" />teste2<br>
    <input class="subcategoria" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" value="3" />teste3<br>
    <input class="subcategoria" type="checkbox" name="subcategoria[]" value="4" />teste4
</form>
```

Comment: Adicionei um novo script a minha resposta lá embaixo. Fiz um tratamento onde a array `checados` só vai ter os valores dos boxes checados.

Comment: no php   $id = implode( ",", $_GET['subcategoria'] );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de id trabalhe com classes

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".teste").click(function(e) {
            var checados = [];
            $.each($("input[name='teste[]']:checked"), function(){            
                checados.push($(this).val());
            });
            console.log(checados.join(", "));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" class="teste" value="teste1" />teste1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" class="teste" value="teste2" />teste2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" class="teste" value="teste3" />teste3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" class="teste" value="teste4" />teste4<br>
</form>
```

> Os `ids` são uma forma de identificar um elemento, e devem ser ÚNICOS para cada elemento. [**id - Mozilla Developer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

- O método `push` é usado para adicionar um ou mais itens no array. [**push -
  Mozilla Developer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

A pergunta foi editada e da forma que está agora não vejo o porque de se usar jquery quando se pode fazer o pretendido com o b a ba. Veja a seguir:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" value="teste1" />teste1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" value="teste2" />teste2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" value="teste3" />teste3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" value="teste4" />teste4<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="opcao" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP

```
$opcao = $_POST["opcao"]; // 2

$id = implode( ",", $_POST['teste'] ); // com os 4 marcados,  teste1,teste2,teste3,teste4
```

Comment: Leo, obrigado pela ajuda. Atualizei o post la em cima. Como faço para que o ID de cada checkbox seja enviado via GET e separado por virgula, exemplo `?id=2,3,4&opcao=2` a media que for marcando ou desmarcando mudar no GET.

Comment: Me ajuda novamente?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve atribuir um id diferente para cada elemento. Um id deve ser único numa página:

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste1" value="teste1" />teste1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste2" value="teste2" />teste2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste3" value="teste3" />teste3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste4" value="teste4" />teste4
</form>
<script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("input").click(function(e) {
      alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste1" value="teste1" />teste1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste2" value="teste2" />teste2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste3" value="teste3" />teste3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" id="teste4" value="teste4" />teste4
</form>
```

**OUTRA RESPOSTA:**

Altere o script para:

```
var checados = [];
$(".subcategoria").click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $.get("inc_habilidades.php",
                {id:checados.push(this.value),  opcao:'2'},
                function(valor2){
                    $("#habilidades").html(valor2).chosen("destroy");
                }
            )
        }else{
            checados.splice(checados.indexOf(this.value),1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Atualizei o post inicial. Consegue me ajudar novamente?

Answer (score 0):

Faça um for:

```
<script>                                                                    
       var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('teste[]');          
       for($i=0; $i<$checkbox ; $i++){                       
          checkbox[i].val();                                                  
       }                                                              
</script>
```

Comment: Atualizei o post inicial. Consegue me ajudar novamente?